# How do resources talk to each other from different namespaces?

Tags: kubernetes

Conditions:
I have a *3 tier application* to deploy using Kubernetes. I have created **two namespaces** for *backend* and *frontend* respectively.

Problem:
I want to know how would my **backend** talk to the **frontend** or vice versa.

In simple words, how do backend and frontend communicate if they are in different namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application will talk to each other using the **Kubernetes service**.

So generally traffic flows moves inside K8s cluster is like

```
Incoming traffic to any specifc application > Kubernetes service > Kubernetes deployment > PODs > Containers
```

So now imagine all your application running inside on Virutal environment. Where they can talk to each other using just the service name. Instead of using IP now you can use service to resolve to IP automatically. Same we do with `www.google.com` IP managed by DNS automatically.

For **cross namespace** also you have to give the service name.

```
service-y.namespace-b.svc.cluster.local
```

The **format** will be something like

```
<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

where your `.svc.cluster.local` will be auto appended if don't use also.

Kubernetes service : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Here is example connecting & deploying the application using different services : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/

**Service 1** will connect to **service 2** using just by name.

MySQL service name is : **wordpress-mysql**

WordPress will get connected to **MySQL** using just service passing to environment.

```
      - image: wordpress:4.8-apache
        name: wordpress
        env:
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
          value: wordpress-mysql
```

now if it's another **namespace** you just need to append **namespace** name.

```
          - image: wordpress:4.8-apache
            name: wordpress
            env:
            - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
              value: wordpress-mysql.my-new-namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways: internal-only and external.

For both, create a kubernetes service for the front and back end services.

For external, the service type must `LoadBalancer`. You install the [External DNS](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns) plugin which will let you create an external DNS name that you can access by the other service. This will also allow you to access the service outside the cluster if you wish.

For internal, you make the service type `ClusterIP` or `NodePort`. When you create the service, you can then access them using the format: `service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local`

For example, an `nginx` service running on the namespace `internal` would be accessed as the DNS name `nginx.internal.svc.cluster.local`

This service cannot be accessed outside of the cluster.

You can sometimes drop the `cluster.local` part, but I include it as habit.

Answer (score 1):

applications can communicate with other services outside their namespace , just use the correct [dns name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

```
<Service Aame>.<Namespace Name>.svc.cluster.local
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for frontend and backend, and then you can communicate using:

- (Recommended) a **DNS names of the services** `<service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local` which will be always the same
- (Not recommended) a IP address of the services (but they will be different with each re-creation of the service)

Example and further explanation below.

Let's create deployments with 3 replicas - one in `default` namespace, one in `test` namespace:

```
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx --replicas=3
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx --replicas=3 -n test
```

For each deployment we will [create service type ClusterIP using `kubectl expose`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#expose)(It's the same if I had created a service from a yaml file:):

```
kubectl expose deployment nginx --name=my-service --port=80
kubectl expose deployment nginx --name=my-service-test --port=80 -n test
```

Time to get IP addresses of the services:

```
user@shell:~$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   64d
my-service   ClusterIP   10.107.224.54   <none>        80/TCP    12m
```

And in `test` namespace:

```
user@shell:~$ kubectl get svc -n test
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
my-service-test   ClusterIP   10.110.51.62   <none>        80/TCP    8s
```

I will exec into pod in default namespace and `curl` IP address of the `my-service-test` in second namespace:

```
user@shell:~$ kubectl exec -it nginx-6799fc88d8-w5q8s -- sh
# curl 10.110.51.62
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
```

Okay, it's working... Let's try with hostname:

```
# curl my-service-test
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: my-service-test
```

Not working as expected. Let's check `/etc/resolv.conf` file:

```
# cat resolv.conf
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search test.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

It's looking for [hostnames only in namespace where pod is located](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/#does-the-service-work-by-dns-name).

So pod in the `test` namespace will have something like:

```
# cat resolv.conf
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search test.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

Let's try to curl `my-service-test.test.svc.cluster.local` from pod in default namespace:

```
# curl my-service-test.test.svc.cluster.local
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
```

It's working.

If you have problems, make sure you have a proper [CNI plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) installed for your cluster - also check this article - [Cluster Networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/) for more details. If you are using some cloud provided solution (like AWS EKS or GCP GKE) you should have it by default.

Also check these:

- [Access Services Running on Clusters | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/)
- [Service | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)
- [Debug Services | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/)
- [DNS for Services and Pods | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)